# E: Unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, dependencies

every time I try to install something or just simply use `apt-get update` I get an error saying something about Unmet Dependencies.

```
root@xxx:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading list of packages... Ready
Building dependency tree
Read information about status... Ready
You might want to run "apt-get -f install", to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.1 : Requires: mysql-server-core-5.1 (= 5.1.61-0+squeeze1) but 5.1.63-0+squeeze1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try to use -f.
root@ks203255:~#
```

How can I fix this? And because of the fact that it has something to do with mysql (I'm running website and game server) do I have to do a backup and should I be worried about my databases?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `mysql-server` is requesting an old version of`mysql-server-core`. Remove the version you have currently (5.1.63-0+squeeze1) and install the version it is requesting (5.1.61-0+squeeze1). Back up any important files.

Comment: What command should I use for that? `apt-get remove mysql-server-core` and `apt-get install mysql-server-core-6.1.61-0`?

Comment: That would do the trick I think, but you might want to use `-f` on the uninstalling so your base package `mysql-server` won't be uninstalled. I dont know the specific syntax, so I suggest looking it up.